# How to pass an array through Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity?

Tags: powershell, office365

I would like to add a user to several Office365 groups in one go.

My code is as follows:

```
$OfficeGroups = @("Egg_Group", "Chicken Group", "Soup Group")

    foreach ($Group in $OfficeGroups)
    {
    $AddParams = @{
        Identity = $Group 
        LinkType = 'Members'
        Links    = $Username
    }
    Add-UnifiedGroupLinks @AddParams
    }
```

I am unable to pass an array of groups through the -Identity parameter. Is there an alternative cmdlt I could use? I have tried

```
Add-DistributionGroupMember
```

but it still doesn't work. Is this an impossible task?

Comment: Do you need to pass an array? You could just create the array, and then `foreach` through it.

Comment: @TobiasKKS I tried to do that and got the following error: 

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.UnifiedGroupIdParameter".

Comment: Can you post your loop code? I can't see why you passed type is an ArrayList if you're correctly passing each element of the array. Just edit the code in your question

Comment: What happens if you don't use splatting, and just have `Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $Group -LinkType 'Members' -Links $Username` inside your `foreach` loop?

Comment: Hi @TobiasKKS, it only pulls the first item of the array "Egg_Group" and adds that as a group. It ignores the rest of the items in the array.

Comment: Does the loop exit after the first called of `Add-UnifiedGroupLinks`? Try to print some text after its called, and see if it prints 3 times (if your array length is 3).

Comment: @TobiasKKS I have edited the question and added the output of Write-Host. Many thanks

Comment: What are you outputting here? The `$Group` variable?

Comment: @TobiasKKS Yes, each group and then the array of groups.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with an `array` of group names it should be sufficient to just loop through them:

```
$OfficeGroups = @('Egg_Group', 'Chicken_Group', 'Soup Group')

foreach ($Group in $OfficeGroups) {
    $AddParams = @{
        Identity = $Group 
        LinkType = 'Members'
        Links    = $Username
    }
    Add-UnifiedGroupLinks @AddParams
}
```

Note: It's always better to use `splatting` i.e. a `hashtable` to feed parameters to your function if you want to make it look more readable.

Comment: I tried this method and it only added the first item in the array, "Egg_Group"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try looping through your array like this?

```
$OfficeGroups = @("Egg_Group", "Chicken Group", "Soup Group")
$OfficeGroups | ForEach-Object {Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $_ -LinkType 'Members' -Links $Username}
```